# why use binding in sql

Tags: php, sql

i was asking for a good explanation to explain to me why use binding in sql i read that it helps against sql injection but i couldn't get it clear can anyone explain it for me thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While writing queries in SQL always prefer using the Binding
 Variables. Here's why:

Everytime a query is executed, it is first checked into the Shared
 Pool to see whether the query was executed before or not. If yes, then
 its execution plan is used again to execute the new query. If no, Hard
 Parse is done by the database. The query is parsed, working out the
 various execution paths and coming up with an optimal access plan
 before it can be executed. Hard parsing is very CPU intensive, and
 involves obtaining latches on key shared memory areas.

So, lets take an example: Hide   Copy Code

```
  `select * from table1 where salary = 2000`
```

Now if the value 2000 changes everytime with input from user, the
 query will never be unique and will be hard parsed everytime,
 generating extra CPU burden.

Solution: Binding Variables Example: Hide   Copy Code

```
  `select * from table1 where salary = :salary`
```

Now this makes the statement unique everytime and just the values
 change in it, reducing the Hard Parse overhead. Every reference to a
 PL/SQL variable is in fact a binding variable.